# What literal expression has type `void`?

Tags: zig

In Zig 0.9, I need a literal expression that has type `void`, for use as the context parameter to `std.sort.sort`, so that my `lessThan` function signature is semantically accurate. Is there some?

I tried these but to no avail:

```
const ek = @import("std").io.getStdOut().writer();
test "void" {
    const kandidati = .{ type, u0, .{}, void, null, undefined };
    inline for (kandidati) |k|
        try ek.print("{}, ", .{@TypeOf(k)});
    try ek.print("\n", .{});
}
```

giving

```
Test [0/1] test "void"... type, type, struct:31:37, type, @Type(.Null), @Type(.Undefined), 
All 1 tests passed.
```

I don't want to use a dummy variable like `const v: void = undefined;`; that's too verbose.

For reference, using `void` as the context parameter to `std.sort.sort` with a `lessThan` function that takes a parameter of type `void`, gives an error message like

```
error: expected type 'fn(type,anytype,anytype) anytype', found 'fn(void, Type1, Type1) bool'
```

Answer (score 5):

The expressions `void{}`, `@as(void, undefined)`, and `{}` have type `void`, for example. You can see `{}` used in the standard library test cases for `std.sort.sort`.

Answer (score 2):

The "canonical" way of getting the void value is to use an empty block.